# How can I execute a plug-in, declared on parent pom.xml, on a spesific child pom.xml in Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am working on a Java EE project that consists of a parent project, and a list of sub-projects (modules). I have declared and configured a plug-in on the parent project's **pom.xml** within a `<pluginmanagement>` tag as follows:

**Parent pom.xml**

```
...
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <!-- inmem-db-plugin -->
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.btmatthews.maven.plugins.inmemdb</groupId>
      <artifactId>inmemdb-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${version.inmemdb-plugin}</version>
      <inherited>true</inherited>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>runDB</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <monitorKey>inmemdb</monitorKey>
            <monitorPort>11527</monitorPort>
            <daemon>true</daemon>
            <type>derby</type>
            <database>localDB</database>
            <username>${user}</username>
            <password>${pass}</password>
            <sources>
              <script>
                <sourceFile> create - data.sql </sourceFile>
                <sourceFile> create - table.sql </sourceFile>
              </script>
            </sources>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>stopDB</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>stop</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>

    ...
```

And then I have referenced it on the child's **pom.xml** file:

```
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.btmatthews.maven.plugins.inmemdb</groupId>
            <artifactId>inmemdb-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
```

From what I have read on the internet, this seems to be the right way of making sure that the specific plug-in will be used only on the specific module that i have referenced it.

But, When I run the `mvn install` command, the plug-in that it is needed to run wont show up at all. Is there anything else that it is needed to be done, in order for the plug-in to run on a spesific module only?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** I replaced the wrong `<phase>` values with valid ones, but still when I enclose the plugin with `<pluginmanagement>` the plugin wont run at all.

Comment: Are you sure that  `pre-test` phase is an actual right phase ? Did you mean test or pre-integration-test ?

See here : https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Comment: @gtosto thanks for the quick response, the thing is that when im not assigning a phase on the parent pom.xml, the plugin is running normaly, but not from the child module. i will quick edit that so it wont cause any confusion. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent > child configuration looks correct i.e. define the plugin in `pluginManagement` in the parent and then engage it in the child by including it `build/plugins`. But this looks incorrect to me: `<phase>pre-test</phase>`, `pre-test` is not a valid phase in the Maven lifecycle and hooking your plugin up to a non existent phase will prevent it from being run. I think the correct plugin configuration is:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.btmatthews.maven.plugins.inmemdb</groupId>
  <artifactId>inmemdb-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${version.inmemdb-plugin}</version>
  <inherited>true</inherited>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>runDB</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        ...
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

I suspect you might have been using the 'phases' pre-test and post-test to start and stop the in-memory DB as/when your test phase starts and stops? If so, then the correct Maven phases are:

- `pre-integration-test`
- `post-integration-test`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response as well. The problem is that im running some simple JUnit test and not intergration test cases. does this change anything in your answer? @glitch

Comment: There are no hooks in the Maven build lifecycle for pre-simple-test and post-simple-test. Those hooks only exist for 'integration tests'. So, if you want to use this plugin to start and stop an in-memory db as part of your test phase then I think you'll have to use 'integration tests'. You may want to look at the docs for that plugin to see if there is some alternative. However, choosing a non existent phase (pre-test) does not achieve what you want, instead the choice of a non existent phase just prevents Maven from running this plugin at all.

Comment: What if i use the 'test' phase of the maven build lifecycle for the 'runDB' execution and the default one for stopping the db? I've read that the 'test' phase is run earlier than the 'integration-test'... I will make some changes and i will let you know if that was the solution.

Comment: I changed the '<phase>' values, but still, when i enclose the plugin in the '<pluginmanagement>' tag, the child module wont run the plugin at all.